# Are Gateway API CRDs supported in Minikube and Kind?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, minikube, istio-gateway, kind

I'm trying to install Gateway into my Kind cluster using Gateway API CRD by following a tutorial from https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/

I had no problem with this command `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.17/samples/bookinfo/gateway-api/bookinfo-gateway.yaml | kubectl apply -f -`

But, command `kubectl wait --for=condition=ready gtw bookinfo-gateway` gave me this:

```
error: timed out waiting for the condition on gateways/bookinfo-gateway
```

I tried this in Minikube as well without any success.

Are these CRDs supported in both k8s (Minikube & Kind) platforms?

Comment: To wait for your pod to be ready, prefer to filter by label, rather than specifying pod id in kubectl wait command:1. $ kubectl -n nxs-r1-prod wait pod/rabbitmq-7575b7f589-dsdhl --for=condition=Ready --timeout=-1s
pod/rabbitmq-7575b7f589-dsdhl condition met 2. # use 'wait' to check for Ready status in .status.conditions[]
kubectl wait pods -n default -l run=mynginx --for condition=Ready --timeout=90s
3. $ kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod -l app=gateway pod/gateway-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx condition met 4. $ kubectl rollout status deployment gateway deployment "gateway" successfully rolled out

Answer (score 0):

As [Istio tutorial](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/bookinfo/#determine-the-ingress-ip-and-port) mentions, your k8s cluster should support LoadBalancer. In Minikube, you have to start a tunnel (and keep it open) to use LoadBalancer.

```
minikube tunnel
```

Once tunnel is up, istio-ingressgateway LB gets EXTERNAL-IP like below. Then the traffic is sent to ingress gateway.

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                      AGE
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.97.104.172   127.0.0.1     15021:32621/TCP,80:32453/TCP,443:30142/TCP,31400:32713/TCP,15443:32441/TCP   25m
```